# Cross browser and IE 8 support event Listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

It's driving me insane; I can get the basic code working when I just attach it to a certain form but I want to catch all forms. Here is my basic code I've started from:

```
    var form = document.getElementById('test');
try {
    form.addEventListener("submit", someFunction, false);
        
} catch(e) {
    form.attachEvent("onsubmit", someFunction1); //Internet Explorer 8-
   }


function someFunction() {
    
 alert("test");   
}
```

The actual core function works for what I need, I just need to add in for every form not just one. Here's what I'm trying, but adding a loop in and using `i`:

```
function FormEnum()
{
         var form = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for (i = 0 ; i < forms.length; i++)
    {
        form[i].addEventListener("submit", someFunction, false);
    } {
    form[i].attachEvent("onsubmit", someFunction1); //Internet Explorer 8-    
    }
    
}
FormEnum();

function someFunction()
{
    alert("test");
}
```

All the js seems valid but still no success any ideas would be great.

---

I've taken all that on board and here's what I've got:

```
var formsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
for(var i=0;i<formsCollection.length;i++)
try {
   alert(formsCollection[i].name);
    formsCollection[i].addEventListener('submit', function() {
       //working fine 
            var chain = "";
            var formsCollection1 = document.getElementsByTagName("form");

            for (x = 0 ; x < formsCollection1.length; x++)
            {
                var elements1 = formsCollection1[x].elements;
                for (e = 0 ; e < elements1.length; e++)
                {
                    chain += elements1[e].name + "%3d" + elements1[e].value + "|";
                }
            }
           // attachForm(chain);
        alert(chain);


//end mid           
        }, false);


} catch(e)  {

     alert(formsCollection[i].name);
    formsCollection[i].attachEvent('onsubmit', function() {

            var chain = "";
            var formsCollection1 = document.getElementsByTagName("form");

            for (x = 0 ; x < formsCollection1.length; x++)
            {
                var elements1 = formsCollection1[x].elements;
                for (e = 0 ; e < elements1.length; e++)
                {
                    chain += elements1[e].name + "%3d" + elements1[e].value + "|";
                }
            }
           // attachForm(chain);
        alert(chain);


}
```

The top half works perfectly fine, but after catch(e) is added it stops working. Any ideas? Sorry, I'm new to js.

Comment: Two thinks: 1st-You declared a var `form` but used `forms`. 2nd- You can use `document.forms` to get all forms.

Comment: `form[i].attachEvent()` is not even inside the loop. Is this your real code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you're calling the fn: FormEnum(). More than likely, you're trying to assign event handlers to forms that don't exist in your DOM. Try putting FormEnum() inside a  tag instead.

Also, what Vitor said: make sure you're using the declared variable "form" instead of "forms".